# Install error: can't select and install software, install GRUB or LILO boot loader

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, alternate

I'm installing ubuntu from alternate CD on a Compaq Presario 1500. The text installer spits out an error on "select and install software" and similarly when I manually select later steps from the menu.

After selecting **Finish the installation** and rebooting, I get a black screen with blinking cursor. The bios menu doesn't seem to have any grub options to change.

I found http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/please-help-ubuntu-alternate-install-459705/ but can't run fdisk or boot rescue from CD. I think Synaptic or Update Manager is occupying a process.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alternative installer is not a liveCD or flash drive. You have to have the Desktop version to be a live version. You may just need nomodeset as black screen after booting is usually a video issue. Change quiet splash in linux line in grub menu. If only Ubuntu you need to hold shift key from BIOS until menu appears and then use e to edit grub entry.

Comment: My mistake, it is alternative, not live CD. It is only Ubuntu but holding the shift key does nothing before or in BIOS.

Is it possible to access or reinstall GRUB from a live CD?

Comment: OP finally installed Ubuntu using a Live CD, instead of alternate CD

Answer (score 1):

From a live CD I looked at `/etc/default` and didn't see a `grub` file. I did a clean install from the same disk and it worked.